# Metaplex SDK, some minted NFTs are missing a name

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

We're minting NFTs with Metaplex SDK, we found that at random, NFT name is missing in blockchain explorer and metadata storage. As a result, tokens aren't showing up in Phantom wallets.

https://explorer.solana.com/address/9SKg6LiT8suiyToATmQ6jjJxWqMcxcV7ALHcwmYSaoqY

Metadata:

[image]

Interestingly, running the following code returns the name ("The Wreath"), but only in a json object. In the root of the response that name is still empty.

```
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
  const mx = Metaplex.make(connection);

  const fetchNft = async () => {
    const asset = await mx
      .nfts()
      .findByMint({
        mintAddress: new PublicKey(
          '9SKg6LiT8suiyToATmQ6jjJxWqMcxcV7ALHcwmYSaoqY'
        ),
      })
      .run();

    console.log(asset);
  };
```

Result:

[image]

For reference, some NFTs we minted in the same fashion do have names, eg: https://explorer.solana.com/address/F1qnUF2gPuf5FsD7whmacw1G7YFLaNHGYC48FAStmCjg

Does anyone have any idea how to go about debugging this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the Mint account of the Master edition NFT that is printing the failed NFT?

Comment: Thanks, this is the account public key 2WTWoinrFGeLtLd3tzsHjqsEnYHs9t1SdHvh2KtFX5FP

This is master mutable:

k3o3wcX67RRKoG67w76EBT2bE9uHtw6VDZpKou9QpL2

Comment: The master edition that you sent was minted 3 days ago, and the mint that you are having issues with was minted 25 days ago. Make sure to send the Master edition that the failed edition comes from.